# Freezing Tensorflow Model Saved by session_bundle.exporter

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am currently following [Train And Export TensorFlow Model](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic):

```
model_exporter = exporter.Exporter(saver)
...
model_exporter.export(...)
```

which produces for each step:

```
  173 Nov 26 17:26 checkpoint
  31M Nov 26 17:26 export-00000-of-00001
 1.5M Nov 26 17:26 export.meta
```

How do I take these files and create a [frozen model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5a5a25ea3ebef623e07fb9a46419a9df377a37a5/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/tool_developers/index.md#freezing) (for example by using [`freeze_graph.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/df871edcff2faf643975b9863100ed41b6da9c3f/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py))?

It looks like `freeze_graph.py` wants a `GraphDef`, but all I have is a `MetaGraph` file. Do I need to extract this first?

Can the `export-00000-of-00001` file be used for the "TensorFlow variables file to load"?

Are there any other flags that I should pass when trying to freeze the model?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.contrib.session_bundle import session_bundle
import tensorflow as tf

export_dir = '/tf_files/00000170/'
output_graph = '/tf_files/00000170/frozen.pb'
clear_devices = True

sess, meta_graph_def = session_bundle.load_session_bundle_from_path(export_dir)

input_graph_def = meta_graph_def.graph_def
if clear_devices:
    for node in input_graph_def.node:
        node.device = ''

output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, input_graph_def, ['flatten5/Reshape'])

with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: Will `session_bundle.load_session_bundle_from_path` be able to load the model which has been exported using `tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder` ?